# Can you convert a primary partition to extended/logical using Gparted?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

Can you? I'm planning to use the bootable image it provides on its website.

Edit: The reason I wanna do that is that Windows? Only supports up to 4 primary partitions. Now I have 5, and the 5th one can not be correctly displayed under win10, but can under MacOs Sierra and can be viewed with minitool (under win10 of course), Gparted etc.

Comment: No *the MBR* only supports 4 primary partitions.

Answer (score 0):

Gparted does not provide an option to convert a primary partition into a logical partition. The only way would be to copy the content of the partition into another partition, then delete the primary partition and create a new partition as a logical partition in the unallocated disk-space. Then move the contents copied before back into the new logical partition.

Remind that you can have only one extended partition (which contains the logical partitions) on drives with msdos-partition-table. On drives with Guid-partition-table (GPT) you can't have extended partitions.

Also keep in mind that the partition should not contain an operating system as such a change would make the operating system unbootable.